# Why are my PNG files becoming corrupt so frequently?

Tags: debian, ssd, corruption, png

I use R/RStudio to draw graphics and maps, and save them as PNG. Along the creation process, I save the same file over and over, to see how it's going, until I get to the final product. Sometimes the file is fine, I send it to someone or upload somewhere, just to find out later (minutes, hours, days...) that the files are not correct anymore (the uploaded version is ok). Sometimes they become blank, other times they become one of the previous versions.

The example below happened just now. I had to make the map in R again. The final product:

[image: perfect PNG]

and the version to which it reversed just in front of my eyes (I saw the icon on Nautilus loading again)

[image: corrupt PNG]

Both files have the exact same size in bytes. `cmd` shows 355,715 different bytes. A previous corruption in other file was much smaller (dozens of different bytes), but the image became blank, though both files also had the same size in bytes.

This used to happen in my previous Debian (10) and happens in the current too (11). Also happened with the previous SSD (120 GB) and with the new one (240 GB, both Kingston). Sometimes the files are stored in the SSD, sometimes in a HDD.

I'm searching for thinks like `Debian PNG corrupt files`, but haven't found anything. There was no power shortage that I noticed. The frequency of this error is too high to be ignored. And PNG's are the only file I noticed getting corrupt, except for a single ODT (where hours of changes had their track lost).

Do I have a virus? What's going on?

EDIT

I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/11798).

Comment: There could be a ton of reasons, starting with a HW failure ending with a bug in this software.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, I know. But I cannot reproduce the error, it's sporadic and arbitrary. So I have no way to eliminate hypothesis. I think it's not a HW failure, because I can always open the corrupted files in Image Viewer. I filed an issue at RStudio GitHub. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This really sounds as if something in your self-designed software is still running and overwriting your files with the ones you call "corrupted".

These aren't what people usually call "corrupted files", they are correct, properly modified files, and the only logical way that would happen is that the software writing the maps still writes them. Maybe you forgot to adjust some file name generation somewhere, so that intermediate files overwrite what you deem an end result?

Comment: Self-designed? I run the R script once and I'm done. I see the image is ok. Later on, the image is not ok anymore. I did not run the script again. Also, how could a blank PNG have the same size in bytes of a detailed image? It's a kind of corruption, though the file still opens in Image Viewer.

Comment: again, the fact that it's its still the same map with a white rectange really indicates its something that has to do with the map generation. PNG is a fairly complicated file format. "corruption" cannot just blank out a rectangle, randomly. That simply doesn't happen.

Comment: Yes, the image with that white rectangle was one of my previous savings, while still determining the area for the legend. However, I'm sure the previous file did not have the same exact size in bytes (mostly considering some totally blank PNGs I encountered that still have had the same size as the complete drawing).

Comment: yeah, sounds like whatever software is generating these PNGs is overwriting them.